# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_scalar'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, matplotlib-basemap

I am importing the `Basemap` package from `mpl_toolkits.basemap`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Tried: Updating the version of matplotlib

But still, it throws an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_scalar'
```

Comment: What is the import statement that is causing this error?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/439) on GitHub, maybe one of these solutions will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it appears to have been fixed in a newer version of basemap. After compiling from source it worked for me

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
cd basemap
pip install .
```

After doing this, you can test your basemap installation to verify it works correctly:

```
cd examples
python simpletest.py
```